# How to put html elements outside the screen without changing the size of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to hide a div outside the screen but the screen size changes when I try.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 1000px; background-color: black; float: right;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 1000px; background-color: gray; float: right; transform: translateX(50px);"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[When I tried this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5SE5.png)

I don't want the slider to appear.

Comment: overflow: hidden on the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using css overflow: hidden property in the body tag, you can get rid from that slider easily. I have attached the code below, run explore. However you can explore more about overflow property. Read the article I have linked below to explore clearly.

[W3 School - css overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 1000px; background-color: black; float: right;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 1000px; background-color: gray; float: right; transform: translateX(50px);"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked thank you. But **how can I do that for the bottom of the screen?**

Comment: if you also want to stop the scrolling option in the bottom, then you can make the height of the body to 100vh. vh means view height. So the height will be taken according to your screens height. replace this with the 1st line of the body tag: <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 100vh">